# Can't print multiple copies

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer

We have a Lanier SP 3510SF that until now has worked great.
However last week something changed and now it's refusing to print more than one copy no matter what we change.

It's definitely an issue with the printer and not the pc as the behaviour is the same when printing to it from other computers

The driver has been updated and is in use on other identical printers without issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you printing via a server? If so, check the printer settings on that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using the universal driver "Ricoh PCL6 UniversalDriver v4.15" however when using that driver the settings in the webinterface under Admin tools > PCL6 mode needs to be set to "universal"

This was the resolution provided to us by the Ricoh service technician that attended onsite after we failed to resolve the issue ourselves.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so this question can be closed

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when your print driver doesn't match the machine's **Paper Type** setting. [Download the manual](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/html/oi/rc2/model/sp35s/sp35sen.htm) and take a look for how to change it.

Basically, if the driver is sending through a job on 'plain paper' and the tray is set to 'Letterhead' or 'Thick' etc, then the printer will stop and *usually* prompt you asking what to do. However, if you've set 'Auto-Continue' to 'Immediate' on the machine within the Print settings (i.e. when you encounter an error, just keep going) the machine will just stop dead after a single copy. Other models may not print altogether.

This happens on the full-size Lanier/Ricoh/Savin/Gestetners as well.

Comment: This worked for my SP C440DN. The paper type wasn't configured on the printer itself, only in the driver. This also fixed my issue of labels printing too fast and smearing - configuring labels on both the printer AND the driver slowed the printer down like it should.